# NoSQL DBMS to query and intersect data by sparse properties

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I am in a research phase for a project, where the subject is to identify/select objects (e.g. email address or phone number) by querying for any number of sparsely populated properties associated with each of the objects.

First, I was thinking of Cassandra, with something like:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  property text,
  property_value text,
  email_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (property, property_value)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;
```

Where it is then easy to retrieve email_id for given property value.

But the need is to query the data by multiple properties and values. I know it is possible to do it client-side by intersecting, but with possibly millions of rows to intersect, it does not seem very efficient to me.

What is the right approach and technology to execute this kind of queries?

Answer (score 0):

Even if C* has good support for sparse data tables (you can add columns dynamically), it seems to me that your query model doesn't fit well. This could be a good fit for relational databases instead.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but in my point of view it boils down to EAV table model, which is not really efficient to query... Or am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed. You need to know what/how to query, you have model your model (pun intended) around them.

Comment: Well how and what is known pretty well, it's simply a model of "give me all emails that are paired to [all|any] of following properties with given [value|set of values]". Which inevitably leads to a query composed of number of intersects and/or unions.

Also, I would like to make use of sharding, so I can have a few "smaller" VMs instead of a big one (as it is then easier to use any leftover capacity of virtualization infrastructure)-